# REGEX find all comments

Tags: regex

I wrote this regex to find absolutely all kinds of comments in file, but it detects `http://` also because of `(//.*)`.

```
(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)|(<!--[\s\S]*?-->)
```

How to modify this regex to not to find http:// etc? Do you think that it's optimal regex for this purpose? If not what do you suggest?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to mix all kinds of comments from different languages into one regex. The regex will become useless.

Comment: @nhahtdh so what do you suggest?

Comment: What do you want to do with this in the first place? Find all comments in HTML + JavaScript?

Comment: You've missed at least VB and SQL comments :)

Comment: @heron: stuxnet's comment is valid, as long as you don't tell us what you want to use this for.

Comment: @heron not at all. Comments are written in a certain (programming) language, with a certain syntax. Using C-style languages, http:// everything here will be a perfectly fine comment, while "this won't be // a comment". Looking at HTML, // doesn't indicate a comment.

Comment: What I'm trying to say: I doubt that a catch-all-comments-of-every-language mechanism is a good idea, and I'm quite sure that regex won't make you happy in this case.

Comment: @stuXnet my regex line find http:// inside blockquotes, where it's assigned to variable as string

Comment: @nhahtdh  I want to catch  all comments of every language

Comment: At least for, HTML, CSS, JS, PHP

Comment: @heron: So you don't care if the output ends up as a meaningless mess?

Comment: @heron - I don't see what you hope to achieve by *using* this regex, just a few that your regex won't pick up are `"smalltalk comment"`, `{# django template comment #}`, and `# python comment`. The smalltalk one is particularly fun since this syntax is what a lot of languages use for strings

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a lot of fun there. :) How about using the negative lookbehind technique with regex if it is supported with the setup you're using. Instead of:

```
//
```

use:

```
(?<!:)//
```

Comment: What about this js: `var x = { a://oops <newline>1};`

Comment: @JamesThorpe, yes, there are also the `^` (start of line) or the full http:|https: lookbehind approach. I think @heron's intelligent enough to pick which one is best along with a good test of various scenarios. I'd use existing code/library myself though. :)

Comment: Even relative protocol urls out there like `//wrongturn.com` @heron ϡ

Comment: The old skool HTTP authentication //username@hostname/ too :)